# ng-include recursively including whole index.html, and giving error "10 $digest() iterations reached"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I am having the following problem with ng-include. What am I missing? Anybody had a similar issue?

1. The template `test.html` is never included.
2. `<h1>Testing</h1>` is repeated many, many times.
3. I get the following
   `Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`
4. Inspecting the html elements in the browser, shows that the whole index.html is recursively included by ng-include.

What I am doing is a simple test with a stripped down index.html

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="static/bower-components/bootstrap-css/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="static/src/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="static/bower-components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="static/bower-components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="static/bower-components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script> 
    <script src="static/src/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="static/src/js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="static/src/js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="static/src/js/filters.js"></script>
    <script src="static/src/js/directives.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body  ng-app="myApp">
    <h1> Testing </h1>
    <div ng-include="'test.html'"> </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**test.html**

```
<h3> included template </h3>
```

In the browser I get:

## Testing

## Testing

....

## Testing

Inspecting the html in the browser, shows the recursive inclusion of index.html:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" class="ng-scope">

<h1> Testing </h1>

<!-- ngInclude: 'test.html' --><div ng-include="'test.html'" class="ng-scope">

<link href="static/bower-components/bootstrap-css/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" class="ng-scope">
<link href="static/src/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" class="ng-scope">
<script src="static/bower-components/angular/angular.js" class="ng-scope"></script>
<script src="static/bower-components/angular-route/angular-route.js" class="ng-scope"></script>
<script src="static/bower-components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js" class="ng-scope"></script> 
<script src="static/src/js/app.js" class="ng-scope"></script>
<script src="static/src/js/services.js" class="ng-scope"></script>
<script src="static/src/js/controllers.js" class="ng-scope"></script>
<script src="static/src/js/filters.js" class="ng-scope"></script>
<script src="static/src/js/directives.js" class="ng-scope"></script>


<h1 class="ng-scope"> Testing </h1>

<!-- ngInclude: 'test.html' --><div ng-include="'test.html'" class="ng-scope">

<link href="static/bower-components/bootstrap-css/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" class="ng-scope">
<link href="static/src/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" class="ng-scope">
<script src="static/bower-components/angular/angular.js" class="ng-scope"></script>
<script src="static/bower-components/angular-route/angular-route.js" class="ng-scope"></script>
<script src="static/bower-components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js" class="ng-scope"></script> 
<script src="static/src/js/app.js" class="ng-scope"></script>
<script src="static/src/js/services.js" class="ng-scope"></script>
<script src="static/src/js/controllers.js" class="ng-scope"></script>
<script src="static/src/js/filters.js" class="ng-scope"></script>
<script src="static/src/js/directives.js" class="ng-scope"></script>

<h1 class="ng-scope"> Testing </h1>

<!-- ngInclude: 'test.html' --><div ng-include="'test.html'" class="ng-scope">

<link href="static/bower-components/bootstrap-css/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" class="ng-scope">
<link href="static/src/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" class="ng-scope">
<script src="static/bower-components/angular/angular.js" class="ng-scope"></script>
<script src="static/bower-components/angular-route/angular-route.js" class="ng-scope"></script>
<script src="static/bower-components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js" class="ng-scope"></script> 
<script src="static/src/js/app.js" class="ng-scope"></script>
<script src="static/src/js/services.js" class="ng-scope"></script>
<script src="static/src/js/controllers.js" class="ng-scope"></script>
<script src="static/src/js/filters.js" class="ng-scope"></script>
<script src="static/src/js/directives.js" class="ng-scope"></script>

<h1 class="ng-scope"> Testing </h1>

<!-- ngInclude: 'test.html' --><div ng-include="'test.html'" class="ng-scope">

<link href="static/bower-components/bootstrap-css/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" class="ng-scope">

    .......
    ...
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: What are the relevant requests made to server. See the network tab for browsers developer console

Comment: there is not much: GET /test.html 304 5ms  (and the .css and .js scripts included in <head>)

Comment: the problem is that GET/test.html is responding with index.html

Comment: Thanks @Chandermani you put me on the right track and I menaged to solve it. I had to fix the path for test.html  <div ng-include="'static/src/views/test.html'"> </div>

Comment: @klode please answer the question so you will be able to close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the error is a wrong path for the html template to be included. If the template path is incorrect and does not match any server route the sever default is to serve the whole `index.html`. This initiates an infinite loop because upon loading `index.html` the `include` template is requested again with the wrong path and index.html is served, and included, again and again and again .. resulting in the "10 $digest() iterations reached" error

In my case the correct path to request the `test.html`from the server is `static/src/views/test.html`.

Changing the include from this

```
<div ng-include="'test.html'"> </div>
```

to this

```
<div ng-include="'static/src/views/test.html'"> </div>
```

solves the problem.